# What is the difference between clicking a button using mouse and clicking using dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, developer-tools

I am working in a website and I want to click a button inside of that website page using dev tools like this :

```
document.querySelector('#selector').click()
```

I'm worried if there is a way for the owners of those websites to find out about clicking from dev tools and I get banned.

Is there any way to find it out ?

Comment: So you want to cheat, and are asking for our help? If you're not using this to cheat, I'd add an explanation why you have a legit use case.

Comment: I am an accountant in Iran and I am trying to create a software to get some salary information and enter it into a website without hours of working and doing it one by one

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to find it out ?

Yes. A synthetic click like that will have the [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) flag set to `false`, whereas for a real event, it's `true`.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("e.isTrusted", e.isTrusted);
});

console.log("Synthetic click:");
document.querySelector('#btn').click();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
```

There are lots of other properties that will be different between the two, such as `clientX` and `clientY`, etc. But that's the property specifically designed to make it possible to tell the difference.

Comment: Is there any other way except this one?

Comment: @amirhosienmajidi - As I said, there are various other properties that will also be different. But they don't need "any other way," this way is reliable.